# What actually happens when I call flush in any language

Tags: file, filesystems, flush

What actually happens when I call `fflush` / `std::ostream::flush` or similar function from any other language?

Does system add my changes to the write queue so it can save all of them after some period of time? If so, what will happen if I shutdown computer after those changes has been added to the queue but before they actually saved to the disk?

I'm asking this because I noticed a [strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38607754/how-to-force-file-flushing) some time earlier.

Comment: What happens if the computer is shut off before data is written to disk? That's almost self-answering, isn't it?

Comment: @Dave Newton I mean, does `flush` just add my changes to the write queue, so they doesn't appear in the target file immediately and there is no guarantee that they will appear there at all?

Comment: The docs for each language's equivalent function should describe its actual behavior. fflush, iirc, is specified to tell the OS to write the output buffer to the disk. But that's in the docs.